# How to take value(index) of inputbox in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

**Angularjs**

```
<tr ng-repeat="advLi in media">
    <td>
        <input style="display:none;" type="text" style="width:35px;" class="form-control" name="mediaindex" value="{{$index+1}}" ng-model="advLi.media_order">
    </td>
    <td>{{advLi.media_name}}</td>
</tr>
```

when I submit form, the "media" list not showing media_order, only showing media_name. How can I get media_order value in controller.

Comment: You have style="display:none;"  and style="width:35px;" in your input element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly you want to display items index value as sequence number in the text box and user can change it later to rearrange the order.

Then I've added `ng-init="advLi.media_order = $index + 1"` in your input tag so that when ever a new DOM element is created in `ng-repeat` then we intialise the `ng-model` value with index + 1 which will display the sequence number on text box.I've also removed the style which hides your text box.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  
  $scope.media =[{media_name:"Still"},{media_name:"Gangsta"},{media_name:"Weed it out"}];
  
  $scope.submit = function (){
    
    angular.forEach($scope.media,function(val,key){
      
      console.log(val.media_order + ' - '+ val.media_name);
      });
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <table> 
    <tr ng-repeat="advLi in media">
    <td>
        <input  type="text" style="width:35px;" class="form-control" name="mediaindex" value="{{$index+1}}" ng-init="advLi.media_order = $index + 1" ng-model="advLi.media_order">
    </td>
      <td>{{$index +1}} </td>
    <td>{{advLi.media_name}}</td>
      <td>{{advLi.media_order}}</td>
</tr>
    </table>
  <button ng-click="submit()">Submit </button>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It may caused by `undefined` initial value of `ng-model`. Try to swap attributes order, or set proper `ng-model`